# Check whether password is correct or not in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In laravel I want to check if user enter current password than check with that password which is store in database in that user data. If correct than continue otherwise give message Password is incorrect.

I am new in laravel so not getting exact idea for this.

Thanks in advance.

```
$('#pwd').blur(function(){
            var oldpwd=$('#pwd').val();
            var uid = $('#id').val();
            console.log(uid);
            if(oldpwd != "")
            {
              $.ajax({
                  url : "{{ url/profile/checkOldPwd}}",
                  data : { oldpwd:oldpwd , uid:uid },
                  type : "POST",
                  success : function(data) {
                    if(data == 0){
                      $("#msg-old").show();
                      $("#msg-old").html("Password is Incorrect!");
                      $("#pwd").val("");
                      $("#pwd").focus();
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    $("#msg-old").hide();
                    $("#msg-old").html("");
                  }
                }
                });
              }
            });
```

Comment: I just try using ajax but not getting how to check with so can you give some idea?

Comment: Check [documentation link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization) for more info regarding authorization or show us your code to help you.

Comment: Above is my ajax code.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

As Hiren has mentioned you can use the default registered hasher as that is passed to the specific UserProvider used. The default is `Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher`.

You can use it a couple of ways:

1. Out of the container

```php
$user = User::find($id);
$hasher = app('hash');
if ($hasher->check('passwordToCheck', $user->password)) {
    // Success
}
```

2. Using the Facade

```php
$user = User::find($id);
if (Hash::check('passwordToCheck', $user->password)) {
    // Success
}
```

3. Out of interest using the generic php function `password_verify` also works. However that works because the default hashing algorithm it uses is bcrypt.

```php
if (password_verify('passwordToCheck', $user->password)) {
    // Success
}
```

Comment: Which do you prefer? Is out of the container the most elegant/fastest?

Comment: Personally I more and more prefer the out of the container (1)

Comment: @LeonVismer What if the existing password hash stored in the database needs to be rehashed?

Comment: @KiranManiya If the work factor was adjusted one can use ```Hash:needsRehash($hashed)``` to check for that.

Comment: @LeonVismer Yup, I got it. I updated the answer as well.

Answer (score 6):

you can use **hash:check** method.

create password using hash:

```
$password = Hash::make('secret');
```

check password:

```
if (Hash::check('secret', $hashedPassword))
{
    // The passwords match...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When the user attempts to access the page, redirect them to an auth page.

Do the ajax call then do the following in your php:

```
public function check(Request $request)
{
    if(Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        // They match
    } else {
        // They don't match
    }
}
```

I havn't tested this so it might not work.

Comment: This won't work. Bcrypt returns different string every time, it is not like `md5`

Comment: @Dastur thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

Answer (score 3):

**Password is correct or not , authenticate password in laravel PHP:  Just do it**

```
public function authenticateEmployee(array $data){

 $email = $data['email'];
 $password = $data['password'];
 $user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();   //get db User data   

 if(Hash::check($password, $user->password)) {   
      return response()->json(['status'=>'false','message'=>'password is correct']);
    } else {
        return 'false';
    }
}
```

**Hit upvote :) Please**

Comment: Maybe it's a better practice to get the email like this `$data->get('email')` instead of `$data['email']`?

Answer (score 3):

Wow it's actually super simple:

```
$request->validate([
     'password' => 'required|string|password',
]);
```

> The field under validation must match the authenticated user's password.

However for people in the future:

> This rule was renamed to current_password with the intention of removing it in Laravel 9. Please use the Current Password rule instead.

So it's

```
$request->validate([
     'password' => 'required|string|current_password',
]);
```

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-current-password)

Answer (score 1):

`if (Hash::check($request->password, Auth::user()->password)) { //Sucess }`

Answer (score 1):

The authentication logic in laravel 6.* is in "vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php".
In this file, you'll find sendFailedLoginResponse() method, which we are going to override on LoginController.php

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {

        if (!User::where('email', $request->email)->first()) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([trans('auth.email')]);
        }
        
        if (!User::where('email', $request->email)->where('password', bcrypt($request->password))->first()) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([trans('auth.password')]);
        }
    }
```

This custom method verifies if a user is present on the database, looking for the unique value that you set up on your model. If the user is present on the database, the password is checked. Then, you can call the errors with

```
@if($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-danger" >
  <ul>
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
      <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>

</div>

@endif
```

on your blade file. Remember that you call those auth.* files from "resources\lang\en\auth.php"

Answer (score 0):

1. Hit the server route with your AJAX call.
2. Check the result of `auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))`
3. Return JSON back with a message and HTTP status code (200 if it is successful, 400 if it failed).
4. Show the message in the `success()` method to a div. If it is an error, show the error message inside the `error()` method to a div.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers have mentioned that where is Hash class located!
We first need to use Hash

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

Now we can use check method

```
Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)
```