# Can i check if a hashed password is equal to a specific value in laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, hash, passwords

in my application, I have a default password (1234 for example) for all users I create, when the user login for the first time he will be asked to change that password

my goal is when a user login I want to check if his password equal to that default value (1234) if that's true I redirect him to the reset page if not I 'll do nothing

so my question is 
how to check that user's password if it's equal or not to a value I have?

Comment: dont you store something other like a login count, last login date, account status flag? seems like an odd way to make a login system.

Comment: it's an app where only the admin can create a user, and since the admin cant assign to that user a password we make a default password 
when the user will be logged in he will be asked to change that password and chose a new one by himself
i have thought about making a column called is_first_login and give it a default value of true and when a user login it will change to false, but thats not a very optimized way to deal with this case since we already can detect the first login by the password

Comment: You should use a password strength meter in your frontend instead of doing what you want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found an answer on StackOverflow that helped me a lot 
You can use it a couple of ways:

Out of the container

```
$user = User::find($id);  
$hasher = app('hash');  
if ($hasher->check('passwordToCheck', $user->password)) 
{
    // Success  
}
```

Using the Facade

```
$user = User::find($id);
if (Hash::check('passwordToCheck', $user->password)) 
{
    // Success   
}
```

Out of interest using the generic php function password_verify also works. However that works because the default hashing algorithm it uses is bcrypt.

```
if (password_verify('passwordToCheck', $user->password))  
{
    // Success    
}
```

[post url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518543/check-whether-password-is-correct-or-not-in-laravel)