# checking if password is equals user password Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have this code

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

@isset($_POST['submit'])
    @if(password==user password or sth like that)
        <p>the pasword is correct</p>
@else
    <p>the pasword is wrong</p>
    @endif
  @endisset
```

what do I need to put in  `@if(password==user password or sth like that)` to use password checking?

Comment: You can use [`\Auth::attempt`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authenticating-users) but you should use laravel's boilerplate methods if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this on laravel then checkout this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38518543/7861806). You should do this control on controllers.

But if you want to do this on form.php, then first connect your database and check it smt like this

```
if($_POST['password'] == $user_password_from_database)
```

And also be careful about hash function. If you saved the password with any hash function then you should decode them. Good luck