# PHP bcrypt to PYTHON bycrypt not giving same values

Tags: python, php, laravel, bcrypt

Hello I am building an API on python to create a user and insert password in database. The problem is that the application is on Laravel PHP and using bcrypt. 
 For example encrypting **"**test1234$%**"** in **PYTHON** **gives** "**$2b$12$rsGZPtjctbI6bSGzS4P3mOSdrABnJuHfnKxEQwvm4KFu72BN3XNKK**" and encrypting same in **PHP** **gives** "**$2y$10$cO2nvRURLRdlW8j6CbWu8OeVlv7dyeozpBZcxVB2nd8hbyILyg7Xa**"

and when trying to login with users created by the api on the app it does not work.
Even if i test with this it does not work the output is **invalid**:

```
$hash = '$2b$12$rsGZPtjctbI6bSGzS4P3mOSdrABnJuHfnKxEQwvm4KFu72BN3XNKK';

//validade hash in php
if(password_verify ( "test1234$%", $hash )){
  echo "valid";
} else {
  echo "invalid";
}

echo("\n".phpversion());
```

on python side used the following code:

```
pip install bcrypt
```

```
 import bcrypt
 
 password = item.password
 bpassword = b"password"
 hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(bpassword, bcrypt.gensalt())
```

on PHP side:

```
if (! function_exists('bcrypt')) {
    /**
     * Hash the given value against the bcrypt algorithm.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @param  array  $options
     * @return string
     */
    function bcrypt($value, $options = [])
    {
        return app('hash')->driver('bcrypt')->make($value, $options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your prefixes differ. See https://github.com/pyca/bcrypt/#adjustable-prefix

Comment: I saw you added a tag "laravel" Is the code is in laravel? If yes, you should use BcryptHasher instead. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38518543/check-whether-password-is-correct-or-not-in-laravel/38519665

Comment: It will *always* create a different hash due to random salts. The important part is that using the appropriate verification function should be able to verify the plaintext password against the hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in the Python api i call bcrypt in PHP using subprocess

```
code = """echo password_hash("""'"'+item.password+'"'""",PASSWORD_BCRYPT);"""
    hashed_password = await myClass.php(code)
```

```
  async def php(self, code):
        p = subprocess.Popen(["php", "-r", code],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        out = p.communicate()
        if out[1] != b'': raise Exception(out[1].decode('UTF-8'))
        return out[0].decode('UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

bcrypt use different salt each runtime that is why its perfect for storing password on database... unless you force it to use the same salt each time it will keep generating different resulting hash